# change value of XML element

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML which is in project folder. I am loading the contents using this

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string testFilesLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string dataSource;
    string xmlFileName = "Claim.txt";

    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(testFilesLocation + @"\Resources"))
    {
        dataSource = testFilesLocation + @"\Resources\" + xmlFileName;
    }
    else
    {
        dataSource = testFilesLocation + @"\" + xmlFileName;
    }
    doc.Load(dataSource);
```

XML has following nodes

```
<ClaimKeyInfo>
    <CompanyID>XXXX</CompanyID>
    <ClaimNum>XX-XXXXX-XX<ClaimNum>
</ClaimKeyInfo>   

<ClaimInfo>
    <ClaimNum>XX-XXXXX-XX</ClaimNum>
    <ClaimSensitivityInd>N</ClaimSensitivityInd>
    <ClaimStatus>Open</ClaimStatus>
<ClaimInfo>
```

I am doing this to get ClaimNum elements

```
    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("ClaimNum");
    for (int i = 0; i< elemList.Count; i++)
    {
        elemList[i].InnerXml = "YY-YYYYY-YY";
        doc.Save(dataSource);
    }
```

I do get both the elements in elemList but I am not able to change the values inside it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us code where you are trying to change nodes' values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx) for that.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("filePath");
var numbers = xDoc.Descendants("ClaimNum");

foreach(var number in numbers)
{
    // do your work with numbers
    number.Value = "123456";
}

xDoc.Save("filePath");
```

Here, the `numbers` are contains [`XElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is your `ClaimNums`.You can change the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and save the `XML` file.If you want to get specific numbers you can use [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method.If you want more details see these documentations:

- [How to: Find an Element with a Specific Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx)
- [How to: Find an Element with a Specific Child Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387053.aspx)